# Notification of network status changes

Tags: ios, swift, network-programming

I need to be notified  when the network status change. I already found how to check network reachability in [other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398664/check-for-internet-connection-availability-in-swift).

Is there any delegate which I can use to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the code from [Apple's Reachability sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) you'll want to register for the `kReachabilityChangedNotification` notification.

Assuming you have a UIViewController subclass that has the method:

```
func handleReachabilityChanged(notification:NSNotification)
{
    // notification.object will be a 'Reachability' object that you can query
    // for the network status.

    NSLog("Network reachability has changed.");
}
```

Then you'll want to register for that notification in your UIViewController's `viewDidLoad()` method like this:

```
let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter();
nc.addObserver(self, selector:"handleReachabilityChanged:", name:kReachabilityChangedNotification, object:nil);
```

See the [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html) and [NSNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/index.html) documentation for how to setup and teardown notification handlers.