# Facing the issue Cannot detect SSID In react native app

Tags: ios, react-native, ssid

I am using react native 64.0.3 version. I am trying to get SSID(using react-native-wifi-reborn package) when the device is connected to wifi. But failed to get.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndwhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>The App uses the location for the network SSID</strings
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>The App uses the location for the network SSID</string>
<key>NSLocationTemporaryUsageDescriptionDictionary</keys
<string>The App uses the location for the network SSID</string>
<!-- <dict>
<key>YOUR-PURPOSE-KEY</key>
<string>The App uses the location for the network SSID</strings
</dicts -->
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>The App uses the location for the network SSID</string>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
```

Comment: You need to add the wifi entitlement to your app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526798/get-ssid-in-swift-2

Comment: Which react-native package did you use for getting SSID in your code?

Comment: I am using react-native-wifi-reborn package to get SSID