# iOS - Handle Internet Disconnection, Firebase

Tags: ios, swift2

I am developing an iPhone app that uses Firebase to retrieve data into a table, I have two questions:

1)I tested my app with no internet and it doesn't crash, but I want to display a message to the user saying that there's no internet and they have to connect to the internet to see the table content.

2)I plan to submit this app to the AppStore, what advice do you have for managing Firebase data query in order for Apple to approve it?

Best,
Anas

Comment: you want to check internet connection then it is already answered . check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34128493/3400991

Comment: hopefully you are still in SO and see this, your questions make me wonder what limits apple has set for firebase query that you were worried about being rejected?

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661137/how-to-detect-internet-connection-with-firebase-database-using-swift3).

If you want to learn more about Detecting Connection State, have a look at the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state), also to get the code for the lastest version of swift.