# How to detect internet connection with Firebase Database using Swift3?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Can any one help me to detect internet connection with Firebase Database using Swift 3? I am using this function to download data from database.

```
  func loadData(){


    Ref=FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    Handle = Ref?.child("Posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "Des").queryEqual(toValue: "11").observe(.childAdded ,with: { (snapshot) in

        if  let post = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

            let img = Posts()

            img.setValuesForKeys(post)

            self.myarray.append(img)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

        }else {


        }

    })

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to detect whether your app has a connection to the Firebase Database backend, you can listen for `/.info/connected`. This example from the [Firebase documentation on detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) should do the trick:

```
let connectedRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath(".info/connected")
connectedRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    if let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool where connected {
        print("Connected")
    } else {
        print("Not connected")
    }
})
```

**Swift 3.1**

```
let connectedRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
    connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    if let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool, connected {
        print("Connected")
    } else {
        print("Not connected")
    }
})
```

**Objective C**

```
FIRDatabaseReference *connectedRef = [[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:@".info/connected"];
    [connectedRef observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
   if([snapshot.value boolValue]) {
    NSLog(@"connected");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"not connected");
  }
}];
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the app is launched with no internet connection.

Comment: It seems that the response block doesn’t execute if the app is launched with no internet connection. Might be an issue with the version of firebase I’m using.

Comment: This does not work if I enable network link conditioner on a profile with 100% packet loss, it always shows as connected when in fact it has no connection to firebase. Any ideas how to get around that?

Comment: Frank, Is there something similar for testing FireStore connection?

Comment: Firestore uses a different protocol, so there's no similar approach. The docs describe a presence solution for Firestore that uses the Realtime Database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

Comment: Swift 5 and newer Firebase:         let connectedRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
        connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            if let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool, connected {
                print("Connected")
            } else {
                print("Not connected")
            }
        })