# NSURLSession return no connection error when launching after sleep mode

Tags: ios, iphone, error-handling, connection, nsurlsession

In my app, I use NSURLSession to download data from a server.
The download happens in two scenarios:
 1. on app launch
 2. if refresh button pushed

I noticed one issue with the following operation:

1. Open my app
2. Put iPhone into sleep mode
3. Awake iPhone out of sleep mode
4. Push refresh button
5. ERROR  - I get "no connection error"
6. Push refresh button again - download starts with success

It seems like my app doesn't have an internet connection active each time iPhone awakes from sleep mode. But it restores connection when I push refresh for the second time.

Comment: when you call api... first check internet connectivity... this will restore internet connection before calling any api

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma Could you please provide any links on how to check connectivity? I think there should be an approach other than calling my api twice: first to get an error but restore connection and second to download data. I found one advise  with reachability class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-in-swift-2-ios-9 Didn't test it yet, but some people told that it does not work with 3G connection