# Check connection: is valid or not

Tags: ios, swift, rabbitmq

I use RabbitMQ and create new connection:

```
let delegate = RMQConnectionDelegateLogger()
conn = RMQConnection(uri: "...", delegate: delegate)
conn.start()
ch = conn.createChannel()
```

How can I detect - is this connection valid or not?

Comment: What does it mean that the connection is valid?

Comment: Do you mean to check whether connection is still alive and usable after some time?

Comment: If user hasn't internet connection or URI is incorrect, I must display: "Can't connect to AMQP Server"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you have to start using connection to check whether it is still usable or not. You may yield any network operation over it, e.g. setting QOS, with, say, `prefetch-count = 3` (note, 3 or any other value could be a default and if your client library do not re-send qos when value is already set to the same value, pick some other value).

To prevent server to close connection after some inactivity period you may try to use [hearbeats](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html).

If you have some other platform or environment-specific ways to check for the internet connection you may definitely use it (perhaps [Check for internet connection with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-with-swift) question could be in handy in this particular case).