# Facing Issue with Reachability IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I Created Reachability in one Demo project in that project i have two view controllers if internet connection is there i am displaying OnlineViewController if internet connection is not there I am displaying OfflineViewController. See the following Code which i have implemented in Appdelegate.swift.

```
 var reachability:Reachability?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityStatusChanged(_:)), name: .reachabilityChanged, object: nil)
        reachability = Reachability.forInternetConnection()
        reachability!.startNotifier()
            return true
    }
```

And My function is like This

```
 @objc func reachabilityStatusChanged(_ sender: NSNotification) {

        var remoteHostStatus = self.reachability!.currentReachabilityStatus()

        if (remoteHostStatus == NotReachable)
        {
            print ("no net")
            let testController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OfflineViewController") as! OfflineViewController
            window!.rootViewController = testController
            window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        else
        {
            let testController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OnlineViewController") as! OnlineViewController
            window!.rootViewController = testController
            window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
            print (" wifi")

        }

    }
```

Now my question is i want to implement same thing in my realtime project in that project i have 3 storyboards and mutiple viewcontrollers. so how to display user current screen again if internet connection is there.

Comment: just put it on singleton class

Comment: can you tell me little briefly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my  issue with following code. i am not sure whether my answer is right or wrong.

```
@objc func reachabilityStatusChanged(_ sender: NSNotification) {

        var remoteHostStatus = self.reachability!.currentReachabilityStatus()

        if (remoteHostStatus == NotReachable)
        {
            print ("no net")
            let testController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OfflineViewController") as! OfflineViewController
            window!.rootViewController = testController
            window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        else
        {
          UserTypeValidateCall()

        }

    }.

//MARK:- Validating User Type
func  UserTypeValidateCall()
{
    let Usertype  =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Usertype")
    print("Usertype-----",Usertype)

    if(( Usertype) != nil)
    {
        if (Usertype?.isEqual("Parent"))!
        {
            ParentDashBoardEnter()
        }
        else  if (Usertype?.isEqual("Employee"))!
        {
            TeacherDashBoardEnter()
        }
        else if (Usertype?.isEqual("Admin"))!
        {
            AdminDashBoardEnter()
        }
    }
    else
    {
        LoginScreenEnter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same way use this function in your project and navigate the user to the particular view controller.

For more detail please refer this link.  [Check for internet connection with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-with-swift)

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Reachability
class CommonUtility: NSObject {

    class func isConnected() -> Bool{
        let reachability:Reachability = Reachability.forInternetConnection()
        let networkStatus = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().rawValue
        return networkStatus != 0
   }
}
```

Comment: its a class and you can use with   if CommonUtility.isConnected(){ }  at any class

Answer (score 0):

//Use below link download  it and just drag and drop Reachability Folder to your project

https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

or

pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 4.1'

Note : Here ReachabilitySwift version is based on swift version you have to insatll

```
let reachability = Reachability()!

  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }


 if (reachability.isReachable)
   {
         // your code
   }
 else
   {
       // your code
   }
```

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply . i should check reachability for all classes or else any other option to check directly in appdelegate

Comment: you have to check for all classes (i mean where you want) , there is no option in appdelegate .