# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Error.Protocol'

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I am creating a function where in validates a passcode, I tried to debug it and look for possible solution, but seems I can't look for a better solution for it.

[image: Error Here]

```
 func validateEventPasscode(){
        //Show Loading
        self.view.squareLoading.start(0.0)

        let api = APIService ()

        api.validatePasscode(eventcode: eventCode) { (data, error) in

            guard let eventDetails = self.event, error == nil else {

                if let networkError = Error.self {

                    if networkError == .InvalidCredentials {
                        _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Ooops!", subTitle: "Please enter a valid event passcode")
                    }else {
                        _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Network Error", subTitle: "\(networkError.rawValue)")
                    }
                }

                self.view.squareLoading.stop(0.0)
                return
            }
          guard eventDetails.deleteFlag == false else {

          _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Ooops!", subTitle: "Please enter a valid event passcode")

         self.view.squareLoading.stop(0.0)

        return
       }

      if (eventDetails.closedFlag == true && eventDetails.reopenFlag == false) {
       _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Closed Event", subTitle: "Please check the status of your event and try again")

       self.view.squareLoading.stop(0.0)
       return
      }
```

**Where .InvalidCredentials came from**

```
enum NetworkError: Error {

   case InvalidCredentials
   case custom(String)
   case other

 }

extension NetworkError: LocalizedError {
   var errorDescription: String? {
     switch self {
        case .InvalidCredentials:
            return "Invalid event code"
        case .other:
            return "Something went wrong"
        case .custom:(let message):
            return message
     }
   }
 }
```

I used this link as my reference, for APIService I used in **validatePasscode** [validatePasscode reference](https://gist.github.com/higepon/71f18472f6d4cba77870)

Comment: change your `Error.self` to `error`

Comment: From where does `.InvalidCredentials ` comes from? Are you using custom Error?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that line? Post the `validatePasscode ` function also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to cast your `error` to an object of the `Error` type, which can be done like this

```
               if let networkError = error as? Error {

                if networkError == .InvalidCredentials {
                    _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Ooops!", subTitle: "Please enter a valid event passcode")
                }else {
                    _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Network Error", subTitle: "\(networkError.rawValue)")
                }
            }
```

**Edit - Here's your code fixed**

```
enum NetworkError: Error {
   case invalidCredentials
   case custom(String)
   case other
}

extension NetworkError: LocalizedError {
   var errorDescription: String? {
     switch self {
        case .invalidCredentials:
            return "Invalid event code"
        case .other:
            return "Something went wrong"
        case .custom(let message):
            return message
      }
   }
}

func validateEventPasscode() {
        //Show Loading
        self.view.squareLoading.start(0.0)

        let api = APIService()
        api.validatePasscode(eventcode: eventCode) { (data, error) in

            guard let eventDetails = self.event, error == nil else {
                guard let error = error as? NetworkError else { return }

                switch error {
                case .invalidCredentials:
                    _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Ooops!", subTitle: "Please enter a valid event passcode")

                case .custom(let message):
                    print(message)

                case .other:
                    _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Network Error", subTitle: "\(networkError.rawValue)")
                }


                self.view.squareLoading.stop(0.0)
                return
            }

            guard !eventDetails.deleteFlag else {
                _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Ooops!", subTitle: "Please enter a valid event passcode")
                self.view.squareLoading.stop(0.0)
                return
            }

            if eventDetails.closedFlag, !eventDetails.reopenFlag {
                _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Closed Event", subTitle: "Please check the status of your event and try again")

                self.view.squareLoading.stop(0.0)
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: casting from Error to Error is pointless, you just need to unwrap the optional type `Error?`.  `if let error = error {`. Or cast it to a custom error type `as? NetworkError`

Comment: Error is just a protocol, there is no  `.InvalidCredentials` property.

Comment: @LeoDabus He might've declared an `Error` conformist also named Error.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't think he has declared  something like `enum Error: Swift.Error {`

Comment: I saw some other guy on here that did exactly that, lol. IDK how common it is for beginners, I can see how `Error` might confuse someone learning Swift.

Comment: I have done that as you can see in this answer but I have declared it nested in a structure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-with-swift/30743763#30743763

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what he did as well. If he'd post his `APIService.validatePasscode` we could know more. Maybe the solution is just casting it to `APIService.Error`.

Comment: I edited my post. I added the codes for _enum_ and my reference for _APIService_ . I did try to debug my codes with your suggested answers but I encountered error _Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NetworkError' and '_' _  in line _if networkError == .InvalidCredentials_. Thank you

Comment: I also included the used of _eventDetails_ in my code.

Comment: @OscarApeland Thank you, It worked for me. When I build and run my app, it succeeded but unfortunately, when I Input the eventcode whether valid code or not, configureAALoading is running but when it checks the conditions, nothing happens and it goes back to a clear textfield. No _eventDetails_ retrieved when I enabled the breakpoints. Hope you could help me in this new issue. Thank you

Comment: @pchocoios Glad to head it solved your issue! I don't understand your follow-up question, please rather post it as a new, separate question. Remember to include as much relevant code as possible!

Comment: @OscarApeland here's the link of my _New Question_ . Hope you could check on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878588/how-to-retrieve-data-from-api-server-in-a-sign-in-page . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to optional bind the optional `error` **parameter**, not the non-optional `Error` **type**.

I recommend this syntax (`eventDetails` seems to be unused)

```
func validateEventPasscode(){
    //Show Loading
    self.view.squareLoading.start(0.0)

    let api = APIService ()

    api.validatePasscode(eventcode: eventCode) { (data, error) in
        if let networkError = error {
            if networkError == .InvalidCredentials {
                _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Ooops!", subTitle: "Please enter a valid event passcode")
            } else {
                _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Network Error", subTitle: "\(networkError.rawValue)")  
            }
        } else {
            self.view.squareLoading.stop(0.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I edited my code posted. I added the _eventDetails_ part. Thank you