# Connecting wifi without internet not recognised with NetworkReachabilityManager or Reachability

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, reachability

When trying to check internet connectivity I have a problem.
When using alamofire NetworkReachabilityManager on a wifi with no internet like so:

```
import Alamofire

class Connectivity {
class func isConnectedToInternet() ->Bool {
    return NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable
 }
}
```

This is the implementation:

```
    if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet() {
        print("Yes! internet is available.")
    } else {
        print("No! internet is not available.")
    }
```

I am getting: "Yes! internet is available." when there is no active internet connection (checked with Safari).

Tried also this one with Reachability:

```
import Reachability

 class ReachabilityManager: NSObject {

var reachability: Reachability!

static let sharedInstance: NetworkManager = { return NetworkManager() }()


override init() {
    super.init()
    
    reachability = Reachability()!
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(networkStatusChanged(_:)),
        name: .reachabilityChanged,
        object: reachability
    )
    
    do {
        try reachability.startNotifier()
    } catch {
        print("Unable to start notifier")
    }
}

@objc func networkStatusChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
    // Do something globally here!
}

static func stopNotifier() -> Void {
    do {
        try (NetworkManager.sharedInstance.reachability).startNotifier()
    } catch {
        print("Error stopping notifier")
    }
}

static func isReachable(completed: @escaping (NetworkManager) -> Void) {
    if (NetworkManager.sharedInstance.reachability).connection != .none {
        completed(NetworkManager.sharedInstance)
    }
}

static func isUnreachable(completed: @escaping (NetworkManager) -> Void) {
    if (NetworkManager.sharedInstance.reachability).connection == .none {
        completed(NetworkManager.sharedInstance)
    }
}

static func isReachableViaWWAN(completed: @escaping (NetworkManager) -> Void) {
    if (NetworkManager.sharedInstance.reachability).connection == .cellular {
        completed(NetworkManager.sharedInstance)
    }
}

static func isReachableViaWiFi(completed: @escaping (NetworkManager) -> Void) {
    if (NetworkManager.sharedInstance.reachability).connection == .wifi {
        completed(NetworkManager.sharedInstance)
    }
}
}
```

The implementation is:

```
NetworkManager.isReachable { networkManagerInstance in
    print("Network is available")
}

NetworkManager.isUnreachable { networkManagerInstance in
    print("Network is Unavailable")
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you check connection? did you try to reach any host something like below.

```
do {
        Network.reachability = try Reachability(hostname: "www.google.com")
        do {
            try Network.reachability?.start()
        } catch let error as Network.Error {
            print(error)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: Is that the right approach? 
what if google is down? - i know it is some what unimaginable but...could happend

Comment: Don't imagine what is unimaginable :D. And yes there are other better approaches but I thought like that I have to try to reach somewhere then I could find out the solution.

Comment: @ironRoei instead of checking google you could ping to your API server to check if communication between your app and the server is currently possible or not

Comment: Thanks guys! ,any other solution? @SahilManchanda

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-with-swift