# Is there an easy and simple way to gather data usage stats on wifi and cellular in Swift?

Tags: ios, usage-statistics

My project is to gather and display data usage on a users phone (wifi + cellular). Is there an easy way for this that also doesn't go against any of Apple's treacherous privacy guidelines?

Comment: Possible duplicate/overlap with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-with-swift

Comment: @AndreasPardeike thanks for that. It's very complicated and detailed, I was hoping for something a little simpler.