# Reachability or device network connection in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a solution stated by "Rajamohan S" in this SO post - [Check for internet connection with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-with-swift)

It works when I test with Wifi On or Off, but when device is connected to cellular network, this returns no network available. I am using Swift 5.

Was anyone able to use this successfully with Swift 5?

***Solution from SO post:***

```
public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
            return false
        }

        /* Only Working for WIFI
        let isReachable = flags == .reachable
        let needsConnection = flags == .connectionRequired

        return isReachable && !needsConnection
        */

        // Working for Cellular and WIFI
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        let ret = (isReachable && !needsConnection)

        return ret

    }
}
```

Comment: If you use the accepted answer of that question it should work for celular network as well