# WKNavigationDelegate method is not called

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wknavigationdelegate

I'm currently writing a web view application using WKWebView, which should show a custom error page when there is no internet connection while loading a page. I've tried to handle this by calling a method of WKNavigationDelegate, but it's never called. I'm new to Swift and I already tried some solutions I've found here on stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myURL = URL(string:"https://google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError)
    {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "no_connection", withExtension: "html")!
        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: If the sole issue is you being unable to check reachability, may I recommend you use something like solutions proposed here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-with-swift

Also, did you try to log something inside the function to see if it is actually not being called and there is no problem with your resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature `func(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) { }` is incorrect.
Try instead `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) { }`.
There should be even a warning, telling you that with the first signature you aren't using a delegate function:
[image]