# How to check if iOS device has access to the internet?

Tags: swift, swiftui, network-programming, reachability

So I am trying to solve some issues related to the internet connection (trying to fetch data from the backend, but failing).
The issue is that we do check if the device is connected to the cellular or wifi, and if it is Wifi, then we say that it is true, and the network is available.

But that is not true. It can be that the device is connected to Wifi, but Wifi is not connected to the internet for any reason.

How do I know if the device really has an internet connection? Can something similar happen on the cellular connection that it is connected, to but has no access?

Update:

Currently using Reachability

```
import Reachability

class NetworkReachability {
   let reachability = try! Reachability()
   var connectionStatus = CurrentValueSubject<Reachability.Connection, Never>(.wifi)
   var isNetworkAvailable: Bool { connectionStatus.value.isAvailable }
}
extension Reachability.Connection {
    var isAvailable: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .none, .unavailable:
            return false
        case .wifi, .cellular:
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that this can not detect if the device actually has the internet access or no.

There is a way to check with Firebase, but takes too long and would slow down the app a lot:

```
import Firebase

    var isAvailable: Bool {
        var isReallyAvailable = false
        let connectedRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
            connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            if let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool {
                isReallyAvailable = connected
            }
            })
        return isReallyAvailable
    }
```

So I am looking for a better way

Comment: you can check and us this library to check internet status https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Comment: @KishanBhatiya sorry, that does not work. Updated my question, with code example, so it is more clear. ReachabilitySwift only checks if the device is connected to internet, but does not check if it has access. There is a way for that with Firebase Database, but this check takes too long and would slow down the app a lot.

Comment: the best approach is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30743763/14260241

Answer (score -1):

You can use Network framework and check connection activity.

```
import Network

class NetworkMonitor: ObservableObject {
    private let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")
    
    var isActive = false
    var isExpensive = false
    var isConstrained = false
    var connectionType = NWInterface.InterfaceType.other
    
    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            self.isActive = path.status == .satisfied
            self.isExpensive = path.isExpensive
            self.isConstrained = path.isConstrained
            
            let connectionTypes: [NWInterface.InterfaceType] = [.cellular, .wifi, .wiredEthernet]
            self.connectionType = connectionTypes.first(where: path.usesInterfaceType) ?? .other
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems like "NWPathMonitor" is the best option to check the connection status. (There is a great article by Paul Hudson on his website)

Comment: share part of the article that is relevant instead of mentioning it