# Wait for download task to finish in NSURLSession

Tags: swift, asynchronous, nsthread

My scenario looks like this: I have a class which has a function in it and this function makes a POST request to a server with NSURLSession. In another function which is not in that class I call that function with the task in it, which runs asynchronously I think. I'm encountering following problem: When I download the JSON response from the server and write it to a variable and return it, the variable I've written to is still nil since it didn't wait for the thread/task to finish downloading and returns the initial value which is nil.

So my question is how can I wait for that task to finish and then continue the whole program.

This is my class with the request function:

```
class DownloadTask {
var json:NSDictionary!
var cookie:String!
var responseString : NSString = ""

func forData(completion: (NSString) -> ()) {

    var theJSONData:NSData!
    do {
        theJSONData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
    } catch _ {
        print("error")
    }

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    if cookie != nil {
        request.setValue(cookie, forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
    }
    request.HTTPBody = theJSONData

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error")
            return
        } else {
            completion(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

}

And this is my calling code:

```
let task = DownloadTask()
task.forData { jsonString in
    do {
        if let json: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options:  NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
            if json["error"] != nil {
                authenticated = false
            } else {
                let result = json["result"] as! NSDictionary
                user.personId = result["personId"] as! NSNumber
                user.sessionId = result["sessionId"] as! NSString
                print("test0")
                authenticated = true
            }
        }
    }
    catch _ {
        print("error")
    }
}
print("test1")
```

The output is:

```
test1
test0
```

And I can't acess the variables user.sessionId after that task.

Comment: Did you end up figuring it out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I said before in the comments of the main post the download `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)` run synchronously to the main thread which means it downloads the data synchronously to the displaying. So in short the `print("test0")` will be executed when the dispatched thread is finished (aka downloaded the data). To fix this I had to use semaphores (I also combined the first code and the second code from the original question):

```
private func downloadData(completion: (String) -> ()) {
   let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

   var theJSONData = NSData()
   do {
       theJSONData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
   } catch {
       completion(String())
   }

   request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
   request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
   request.HTTPBody = theJSONData

   let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
       data, response, error in
       data == nil ? completion(String()) : completion(String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
       dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
   }
   task.resume()
   dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

This may not be the most efficient nor the most elegant solution but in my case I really had to wait for the downloading to be finished else it shouldn't do anything.

Comment: In the latest Swift:  
`let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)`  
`then in the URLSession.shared.dataTask`  
       `semaphore.signal()`  
`_ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)`