# iOS 8 reachability always return false in simulator

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to detect if the phone has internet access or not. I stackoverflowed it and every time i use a library (https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) or i [use recomended class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-in-swift-2-ios-9) it ONLY works on iOS 9.0, but iOS 8 it just returns false (at least in the simulator, i dont know in a real phone). Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. For the life of me, I couldn't figure out the reason why, so had to implement this workaround piece of code that works for both iOS 9 and iOS 8:

```
class func isConnectedToNetwork()-> Bool {

    var isConnected:Bool = false
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://google.com/")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    request.timeoutInterval = 10.0

    var response: NSURLResponse?

    do {
        try _ = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response) as NSData?

        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                isConnected = true
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }


    return isConnected
}
```

Obviously, if Google falls - so does the workaround. But I'm taking that risk :)

Based on answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29050673/2941553