# HTTP request times out. Weak wifi or slow server?

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest

I have a client/server application where the client is an iOS app and the server is a RESTful api. I have received complaints of requests timing out and I know that some/most of the time, this is due to poor wifi connectivity. In these situations I would like to display an error message on the client which indicates whether the request was received by the server.

Is it possible in iOS to tell the difference between a HTTP request that never reaches the intended destination and one that makes it all the way to the intended destination but never receives a response?

Comment: may be your data is high

Comment: i think you can't tell until you get a response from the server

Comment: There is a case that happens when you are connected to the internet but the speed you get 0 kb/sec or something. So reachability still sees it as being connected to the internet but you simply don't receive the speed. In this case only after a long while do you get a *timeout* error.

Answer (score 0):

1. API Call only after you check whether your internet connectivity is reachable or not .show error message if not connected to internet(this is due to poor wifi connectivity)

   Example : [Check for internet connection availability in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398664/check-for-internet-connection-availability-in-swift)
2. When its checked make api call  handle error code  404(never reaches the intended destination) and 504(timeout error code never receives a response) and let user make it success only when status code is 200.But its good to handle 401(authorization error) also.

I don't know which library  you are using that why can't provide any code example right now

**Try Alamofire Library in swift I suggest handled error codes very well.**