# How do I detect change in internet connection on iOS, delegate style?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, moya

I need a function to run only when the system detects there is no internet connection, then another function to run when the system detects an internet connection.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
func onInternetConnection() {
    //Enable actions
}

func onInternetDisconnection() {
    //Disable actions, alert user
}
```

I will also need a way to detect when the system is reconnecting, so I can let the user know it's reconnecting, like in Facebook's Messenger.

How can I do this?

I'm using Moya/Alamofire for my network layer.

Comment: Alamofire have network reachability included, read about it [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#network-reachability), it use block, kinda better than delegate

Comment: Take a look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398664/check-for-internet-connection-availability-in-swift)

Comment: Check [this lib](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift#example---closures) too, it can trigger closures when the status of your internet connection changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works in case of Alamofire

```
import Alamofire

// In your view did load or in app delegate do like this
let reachabilityManager = NetworkReachabilityManager()
reachabilityManager.listener = { status in

  switch status {

  case .notReachable:
    print("The network is not reachable")
    self.onInternetDisconnection()

  case .unknown :
    print("It is unknown whether the network is reachable")
    self.onInternetDisconnection() // not sure what to do for this case

  case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
    print("The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")
    self.onInternetConnection()

  case .reachable(.wwan):
    print("The network is reachable over the WWAN connection")
    self.onInternetConnection()

  }
}
```

Comment: Where can I put this so that `reachabilityManager` is retained?

Comment: You can make it instance variable of app delegate or some singleton.

Comment: Any way to do this without Alamofire, and natively?

Comment: @toast you can download apples reachabiliy code. Just search apple reachability and you can find their sample on developer site

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire and Rechability are library and that have some features to check internet connection. You can use one from that.